# How can I present a new view with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing database search app, and want to show a result view like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iSp3.jpg.

The actionSheet wasn't correct answer.

```
        HStack {
            TextField("SearchText", text: $text)
                .background(Color.white)
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.trailing, -7)

            Button(action: {
                let r = getSearchResult(query: self.text)
                if r is Int {
                    print("ErrorCode: \(r as! Int)")
                } else {
                    self.holder.r = Result(sSearchResult: r as! SearchResult)
                }
            }){
                Text("Search")
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.leading, 3)
                    .padding(.trailing, 3)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a new view, wrap your view in a `NavigationView` and use a `NavigationLink` instead of a normal `Button`. Put your new view in the destination parameter like `NavigationLink(destination: SomeNewView()) { ... }`.

```
NavigationView {
    HStack {

        TextField("SearchText", text: $text)
            .background(Color.white)
            .shadow(radius: 10.0)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.trailing, -7)
            
        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
            Text("Search")
                .font(.system(size: 10))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but isn't NavigationButton deprecated?

Comment: Use NavigationLink instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink